# Url launcher giving ssl certificate error

Tags: android, flutter, webview

I'm launching a Url (Can not share it here) and flutter is giving me error:-
 [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(947)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202,

The code is 
launch(url,forceWebView: true);
If i remove "forceWebView:true" It gets open in the browser and works fine but URL is exposed and I can't do that.

Comment: Found the solution You need to create the SHA-256 keys and need to add it to the network_security_config.xml file under res folder (name it as you want) and add it to manifest under application tag "android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">"

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config more to read here

Answer (score 0):

The error encountered here means that the url you are trying to launch is not trusted as mentioned [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/net/base/net_error_list.h#465):

> The server responded with a certificate that is signed by an authority
> we don't trust.  The could mean:
>
> 1. An attacker has substituted the real certificate for a cert that contains their public key and is signed by their cousin.
> 2. The server operator has a legitimate certificate from a CA we don't know about, but should trust.
> 3. The server is presenting a self-signed certificate, providing no defense against active attackers (but foiling passive attackers).

As mentioned in the comment, a workaround here is to do a [certificate pinning](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CertificatePinning).

[Get the SHA-256](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=tr#api-providers):

> The MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints of the upload and app signing
> certificates can be found on the app signing page of the Play Console.
> Other fingerprints can also be computed by downloading the original
> certificate (.der) from the same page.